# Split string at last number in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I need to split a string into a number (integer) and text (0303txt becomes 0303).

When a document is uploaded I need to take the Document number, which is created on another platform).
Filename: BC1234-XX-YY-A-W-0303.pdf (0303 is just an example, but can be any number)

Now if a user accidently uploads something like this "BC1234-XX-YY-A-W-0303testfile.pdf" or "BC1234-XX-YY-A-W-0303 testfile.pdf", then I need to split that last part of the string so I can use the integer (0303).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you please confirm the names always follow that format? I mean:
BC1234-XX-YY-A-W-[Here the number + string you want to get].pdf

Comment: Yes.that is the standard ISO19650